# Asking on leads on new territory and asking for opinions

Tags: support, scope, opinion-based

I asked a question on Stack Overflow which I guess is more on getting leads to know if there are any systems that satisfy my requirements for which I don't even know what kind of keywords to search for in Google. Its been flagged to be closed on grounds that its against the guidelines that asking for opinions on books and tools.

I have been thinking that this is one of the core use cases of Stack Overflow. And I think the guidelines shouldn't be taken like a match or not boolean functions.

This is the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795239/configuration-management

Comment: You see the community has gotten so low to downvote but not leave any comments. Sad

Comment: The downvote tooltip is the default downvote comment. I wouldn't be surprised if someone downvoted because of lack of research - this has been discussed _a lot_ on meta. (Side note: your SO question's title is reaaaaaaaaaaally bad.)

Comment: Have you looked at [softwarerecs.se] at all?

Answer (score 6):

> [...] this is one of the core use cases of Stack Overflow

It is not. It's off topic. Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems, and problems with using the related tools. It is not a recommendation platform or a discussion forum.

If you want leads on something, find an appropriate chat room. You can get a discussion going there, which is what you need. Or go look in other places on the Internet.

Once you've found two or three products that fit your need, try them out. You can ask specific questions about them if you can't get them to do exactly what you want. (And you know what? If the question is asked well, you might get both an actual answer, and pointers to other tools that might fit your task better.)

The Stack Overflow Q&A format does not work with discussions (by design). Questions that ask for product recommendations end up attracting lots of SPAM, and even the legitimate answers rust and become irrelevant as time goes by.

Stack Overflow is not for everything. Use it for what ut's designed for and it can be a great resource.

Comment: So *requests* for tool suggestions in questions is off-topic in questions, in answers *suggestions* for tools not requested is OK? That would mean "fake a good question and you'll (probably) get what you want". Same rust potential to answers. Perhaps still spam targets.

Comment: No. A suggestion _in addition to_ solving the question (or explaining why it fundamentally can't work) is usually ok (within the usual spam guidelines). Less rust, because the tool suggested will in fact solve that specific problem and unless the tool disappears it is likely to continue doing so. With open ended, broad, recommendations anything goes and anyone with an opinion can post a link to just about anything that's tangentially connected to the Q.

Comment: Yes, it's just that reading your answer I can get to "fake a good question and you'll get what you want". Not looked at it that way before. Perhaps why I had a flag declined :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger 'faking' a good question by actually asking a good question tends not to be a problem.  Well, rather, that it does a good job of stating its problem with something that can be solved - the additional resources are an added bonus. But that still has the challenge of writing down a good problem (which is often hard unless you've actually thought about the problem in the first place that you are encountering).